# How to handle this exception in java or db2?

Tags: java, db2

Can anyone please tell me how **to handle this exception in java or db2**.

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=DECFLOAT, DRIVER=3.63.123
```

I am looking **to generate the scripts automatically from db2 Database**.
How to solve  this Problem? I m new in db2 database.

Answer (score 0):

try catch please! Sql state can be handle using

```
try{
....
}catch(java.sql.SQLException e)
{
=> e.getSQLState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the error code explanation on IBM's knowledge center site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.codes/src/tpc/n420.dita).

You really should give some information about the SQL code which triggers this error, but according to the error description it seems like you might have a SQL query which compares a text value to a number value. DB2 tries to convert the text value to a number but fails because it's not a number. Check your WHERE clauses for comparisons.  If you have variable parameters that are used in these comparisons (in the SQL code generation or as bound variables), make sure the values are what you expect. A null or empty value could be the cause.